# please help me construct this MYSQL Query (date / time)

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I would like to construct a query that fetches results that occurred between NOW and 15 minutes ago, im getting a mysql error when I try the following , can you help me? thanks

```
SELECT *
 WHERE user_id = '000'
   AND date_time < now( )
   AND date_time > DATE_SUB( now( ) , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_id = '000'
>   AND date_time < now( )
>   AND date_time > DATE_SUB( now( ) ' at line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it lacks **FROM TABLENAME**

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
WHERE user_id = '000'
AND date_time < now( )
AND date_time > DATE_SUB( now( ) , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select FROM a table :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `FROM` statement

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE user_id = '000'
AND date_time < now( )
AND date_time > DATE_SUB( now( ) , INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```